# Timestamped measurements from different tables

Tags: sql, sql-server

I am facing a problem for which I need a quick solution (I am not very good with SQL). I have several tables A, B and C, each containing the columns (id INT NOT NULL, value NUMERIC(18,1) NOT NULL, date DATETIME NOT NULL).

Now what I need is to create a query resulting in a table containing four columns, one with the DATETIME and three with the value for each of the tables A, B and C. If there's no value for that particular timestamp in any of the columns we insert NULL.

Please help me with this.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT t0.date, A.value,B.value.C.value
FROM (SELECT date
    FROM A
    UNION
    SELECT date
    FROM B
    UNION
    SELECT date
    FROM C
) t0
LEFT JOIN A ON t0.date = A.date
LEFT JOIN B ON t0.date = B.date
LEFT JOIN C ON t0.date = C.date
```

Comment: This doesn't have the `date` column. Did you change your requirements?